# Fail of guessing game

Tags: c#

So i was learning c# from a tutorial video and the guy on the video showed a guessing game so i wrote the exact code of him

but it has a problem! it does not work accurate

and i guess i see where the problem is but why this guy does not have a problem with it

**Code:**

```
string secretWord = "girrafe";
string guess = "";
int guessCount = 0;
int guessLimit = 3;
bool outOfGuesses = false;

while(guess != secretWord && !outOfGuesses)
{
    if (guessCount < guessLimit)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter guess ");
        guess = Console.ReadLine();
        guessCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        outOfGuesses = true;
    }

    if (outOfGuesses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Lose!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You win");
    }
}
```

I think the problem is on the last else statement.

Comment: Are you sure, that this is exactly the same code as in the tutorial? Double checked the all the `{` `}`s and the if statements?

Comment: Could you point us to the tutorial?

Comment: Yeah. This code definitely doesn't do what you say it does. I believe that second `if` block should be moved to be AFTER (or outside) of the `while` block. In other words, move the last squirrelly bracket to be just above the second `if`. Give that a shot and rerun.

Comment: @zerocukor287 yeah i double checked it but i can still be wrong (gonna check it again after a few minutes)

Comment: @Rand Random https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhQdlIFylQ8&t=9931s 

that is the tutorial and the guessing game part at 2:34:22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems you're missing one closing bracket for the while statement.

```
string secretWord = "girrafe";
string guess = "";
int guessCount = 0;
int guessLimit = 3;
bool outOfGuesses = false;

while(guess != secretWord && !outOfGuesses)
{
    if (guessCount < guessLimit)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter guess ");
        guess = Console.ReadLine();
        guessCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        outOfGuesses = true;
    }
} // <--- this one, to close the while-loop
if (outOfGuesses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You Lose!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You win");
}
```

Comment: I think they've got the brackets all accounted for, however, the closing bracket for the `while` is in the wrong spot. Your correction should do the trick.

Comment: My guess is that he added one last bracket after receiving error message about missing bracket at the end of the code.

Comment: That's a pretty good guess. Definitely feels like a transcription issue (copying code from a video here, so likely).

Comment: @tnavidi oh thanks for your help man i missed that one :)

Comment: @einspert - don't forget to mark answer as accepted - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: @Rand Random im pretty new on stack overflow i did it now sorry :)